# How to make this CSS to be in the middle?

Tags: css

I have a problem with the CSS that I found on google.com
at the moment in trying to turn out this CSS results are not going to the middle ..
I try to edit the CSS but still can not,,, maybe because of my knowledge of CSS is less ..

Its this HTML.

```
<div class='menu'>
<a href='clearsessions.php'><span>Home</span></a>
<a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a>
<a href='#'><span>Buy Followers</span></a>
<a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>
</div
```

CSS

```
.menu:after, .menu:before {
margin-top:0.5em;
content: "";
float:left;
border:1.5em solid rgba(0, 159, 234, 0.3 );}
.menu:after {
border-right-color:transparent;}
.menu:before {
border-left-color:transparent;
}
.menu a:link, .menu a:visited {
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
height:3.5em;
overflow:hidden;}
.menu span {
background:rgba(0, 159, 234, 0.3 );
display:inline-block;
line-height:3em;
padding:0 1em;
margin-top:0.5em;
position:relative;
-webkit-transition: background, margin 0.2s;
-moz-transition: background, margin 0.2s;
-o-transition: background-color, margin-top 0.2s;
transition: background, margin 0.2s;
}
.menu a:hover span {
background:rgba(0, 159, 234, 0.5 );
margin-top:0;
}
.menu span:before {
content: "";
position:absolute;
top:3em;
left:0;
border-right:0.5em solid #9B8651;
border-bottom:0.5em solid rgba(0, 159, 234, 0.3 );
}
.menu span:after {
content: "";
position:absolute;
top:3em;
right:0;
border-left:0.5em solid #9B8651;
border-bottom:0.5em solid rgba(0, 159, 234, 0.3 );}
```

Please Help,, :(

Comment: Adding a link to a live demo or a JSFiddle would help a great deal. Also, indenting your CSS would make it much easier to read.

A minor observation: your closing tag `<\div>` is missing it's right hand bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to your css:

```
.menu{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -212px;
}
```

You need to find the accurate margin-left px's